# C# General Error in GDI+ when saving Image

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I'm trying to save a `System.Drawing.Image` to a File.

This is my code:

```
    using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(defaultPic), defaultPicPath);

    var tempImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(defaultPicPath);
    using(System.Drawing.Image RoundedImage = RoundCorners(tempImg, 90, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent)) {
        RoundedImage.Save(defaultPicPath);
        tempImg.Dispose();
    }
```

In the `RoundedImage.Save(...);` line, I'm getting the Error

> General Error in GDI+.

I am pretty sure the File is not locked by any WPF Control or Image.

Any Help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you provide different path to `RoundedImage.Save(...)` method?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=General%20Error%20in%20GDI%2B&oq=General%20Error%20in%20GDI%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i60.704j0j7

Comment: @krw12572 Sorry, forgot to say that. Another Path obv. works, I am trying to overwrite the Image. I'll just do it hackish and overwrite the original file afterwards.

Comment: I've added the answer. see if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see from your code, you are not releasing the file.

You should,

1. First read the image and create a local deep copy of it(`tempImage`). (Note: Shallow copy using Clone method will not work.)
2. Release the image file.
3. Modify your local copy.
4. Overwrite the original file.
5. Dispose local copy(`tempImage`).

Try following, it should work;

```
Image tempImage;
using(var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(defaultPicPath))
    tempImage=new Bitmap(img);

using(System.Drawing.Image RoundedImage = RoundCorners(tempImg, 90, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent))
    RoundedImage.Save(defaultPicPath);
tempImg.Dispose();
```